# empty array with calendar.getEvents() fullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fetch-api

I try to retrieve the events using the `calendar.getEvents()` function but I get an empty array even though I have events displayed in the calendar.

I first tried to create the events manually and `getEvents()` function works. But when I use the  fetch API to retrieve events form my database, I also get my events rendered but `calendar.getEvents()` gives me an empty array.

I don't understand why.

```
// render initial calendar
window.onload =() => {
    let calendarElt = document.querySelector('#calendar')
    const role = calendarElt.getAttribute('data-role');
    const doctorView = calendarElt.getAttribute('data-doctor-view');
    console.log(role)
    console.log(doctorView)

    let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarElt, {
        initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
        locale:'fr',
        timeZone: 'Europe/Paris',
        slotDuration: '00:45:00',
        slotMinTime: '08:00',
        slotMaxTime: '18:00',
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
        headerToolbar: {
            start: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear today',
            center: 'title',
            end: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridDay'
        },
        buttonText: {
            today: "Aujourd'hui",
            month: 'Mois',
            week: 'Semaine',
            list: 'liste',
            day: 'Jour'
        },
        views: {
            week: {
                hiddenDays: [0]
            }
        },
        businessHours: [
            {
                daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                startTime: '08:00',
                endTime: '12:00',
            },
            {
                daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                startTime: '14:00',
                endTime: '17:45'
            }
        ],

        select: function(start){
            if(!doctorView){
                return;
            }

            //showing up the modal
            $('#appointmentModal').modal('show')

            // sending data to server
            $('#validate-btn').off('click').click(function(){
                let title = $('#patient').val();

                const data = {
                    title: title,
                    datestr: start.startStr
                }

                fetch('http://green-phoenix.test/api/events/new', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data)

                })
                    .then (response => response.json())
                    .then (event =>{
                        calendar.addEvent({
                            'title': event.title,
                            'start': event.datestr
                        })

                    })
            })

            //refreshing the modal

            $('#appointmentModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
                $('#patient').val('')
            })
        },
        events: function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
            fetch('http://green-phoenix.test/api/events')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    let events = data.map(event => ({
                        id: event.id,
                        title: event.title,
                        start: event.datestr
                    }));
                    successCallback(events);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error fetching events', error);
                    failureCallback(error);
                });
        },
        eventDrop: function(info){
            if(!doctorView){
                return;
            }
            let eventData = {
                id:info.event.id,
                datestr: info.event.startStr,
                title:info.event.title
            }
            console.log(eventData)
            fetch('http://green-phoenix.test/api/events/update/'+info.event.id,{
                method:'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(eventData)
            })
        },
        eventClick: function(info){
            if(!doctorView){
                return;
            }

            let eventTitle = info.event.title

            $('#info-patient').text(eventTitle)

            //showing up the modal
            $('#editModal').modal('show')

            //sending request to server side
            $('#confirm-btn').click(function() {

                fetch('http://green-phoenix.test/api/events/' + info.event.id, {
                    method: 'DELETE',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                //deleting on client-side
                info.event.remove();
            })

        },
        editable: function(dropInfo, draggedEvent){
            if(doctorView){
                return true
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        },
        allDaySlot: false,
        navLinks:true,
        selectable: true, // make able to select a slot
    })

    calendar.render()
    let eventsRendered = calendat.getEvents()
    console.log(eventsRendered) // => [] empty array
}
```

Comment: It happens because AJAX/Fetch requests to remote servers happen _asynchronously_ in the background. So at the time your code runs `let eventsRendered = calendat.getEvents()`, the fetch() requests have not completed yet, and therefore have not provided any event data to fullCalendar.

Comment: If you want that event data, it already exists within the events callback ( `.then(data => {`...). So you can just use it from there, if you need it for something.

Comment: 2 more questions:
- isn't there any approach to use calendar.getEvents()  after calendar.render()? 
i would like to render in html all the slots available (without events) so I'd like to be able to use it outside the fullcalendar configuration. 
- is there any way to get the slots in fullCalendar?

Comment: Like I said, you can trigger anything like that from within the events callback - maybe just call a function from within there which accepts the event data and renders the slots. This is also useful if the events get refreshed - really you should be passing the start/end dates of the current data range (as provided by fullCalendar into the events callback via the `info` object) to your API, and writing your server-side code so that it only returns events for the current date range. ...

Comment: ...This is more efficient - this way you don't end up download a whole pile of past/future events which rarely get viewed. If the user changes the calendar date, fullCalendar calls the events function again and passes new dates.

Comment: OK! thanks for the advices! Now all I have to do is code hi hi hi.